# How to insert text at cursor in different program with Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Not sure this is even possible, but if I click on an input field of a program like Slack and then bring up my Electron app. From the electron app, can I set the text input value of where the cursor was in the Slack app. I was using Robotjs in order to set text at the cursor, but it only set the text at the cursor in my Electron app, not where there cursor was previously in another program.

Comment: I think you can hide Electron app to tray, wait some time, (500ms?) and then execute robotjs `typeString`, then optionally get Electron app back from tray. (Using api: `window.minimize()`, `window.hide()`, `window.restore()`, `window.show()`)

Comment: @Alex I'll try that. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @moustache-me-a-question Did you find a solution that worked?

Answer (score 0):

would give RobotJS a try. It appears to do what you need.
robot js : https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

Comment: I tried RobotJS. But it only pastes text at the cursor within the Electron app, not the last opened app's cursor position. I want to insert text into Slack or wherever, not my Electron app. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?